# Rust linker fails when using target-feature=+crt-static on nightly

Tags: rust, static-linking

I am trying to compile [my simple program](https://github.com/frafra/frakegps) statically, as I cannot install any software or libraries on the systems where the program need to run, so I need to ship all the dependencies.

I decided to compiled using `-Ctarget-feature=+crt-static`, as suggested by https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/linkage.html#static-and-dynamic-c-runtimes.

### +crt-static / glibc / rust stable

It should support glibc as well, but it fails:

```bash
RUSTFLAGS="-Ctarget-feature=+crt-static" cargo build
```

Output:

```
error: cannot produce proc-macro for `futures-macro v0.3.28` as the target `x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu` does not support these crate types
```

### +crt-static / musl / rust stable

I then tried to switch to musl, using:

```
RUSTFLAGS="-Ctarget-feature=+crt-static" PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_CROSS=1 cargo build --release --target=x86_64-unknown-linux-musl
```

The produced executable is still dynamic. Please note that I added `PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_CROSS=1` as I get this error otherwise:

```
warning: pkg-config has not been configured to support cross-compilation.
error: failed to run custom build command for [...]
```

### +crt-static / musl / rust nightly

I then switched to Rust nightly and retried:

```bash
rustup default nightly
export RUSTFLAGS="-Ctarget-feature=+crt-static"
export PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_CROSS=1
cargo build --target=x86_64-unknown-linux-musl
```

Output:

```
[...]
error: linking with `cc` failed: exit status: 1
  |
  = note: [...]
  = note: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lwebkit2gtk-4.1: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgtk-3: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgdk-3: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpangocairo-1.0: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpango-1.0: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -latk-1.0: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsoup-3.0: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ljavascriptcoregtk-4.1: No such file or directory
[...]
```

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 and compiling using GCC 11, but I have the same error when using `-Clinker=clang`.

Is there any way to fix that? Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Have you musl toolchain installed? Anyway, try to do `RUSTFLAGS="-Ctarget-feature=+crt-static" cargo build --target=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu`. This would ensure that build scripts and proc macros wouldn't try to link crt statically.

Comment: @AngelicosPhosphoros musl toolchain has been installed using `rustup target add x86_64-unknown-linux-musl`. That target is the default, which gives me the first error (see section `+crt-static / glibc / rust stable`). Specifying the target from the command line, as you suggested, produce different messages, such as `warning: Using [...] in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking` and `/usr/bin/ld: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line`

Comment: Did you tried to link musl version by specifically using musl? It has more changes to work compared to gnu.

Comment: @AngelicosPhosphoros I only tried the options and the flags written in my initial question; I am not aware of any additional tricks to link using musl.